# How to code simple meta-stream with RxJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, stream, rxjs, observable

### Background

It is the first time I am trying reactive programming. 
I have a stream that receives buffers of data from time to time.

When a buffer starts with `02` it means the start of a message, and when it ends with `03` it means the end of the message.

Example:

```
- - - 02 53 44 5a - - - 52 6a 72 7a - - - 62 32 62 0d - 0a 03 - - - - >
```

### Objective

My objective is to fire an event every time I detect a message is completed, with who whole message as an argument.

### Research

After reading several [tutorials on reactive programming](https://gist.github.com/staltz/868e7e9bc2a7b8c1f754) and reading [RxJS](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/tree/master/doc), I know I want to create a [hot observable](https://github.com/Froussios/Intro-To-RxJava/blob/master/Part%203%20-%20Taming%20the%20sequence/6.%20Hot%20and%20Cold%20observables.md).

With my research, I believe I want to create a "meta-observable" or a "meta-stream", i.e., an observable of observables or a stream of streams (confusing as this may be ... ).

My plan is the following:

1 - create an observable for all buffer messages that come in
2 - subscribe to step 1, and create an observable that detects the beginning of a message ( `02` ) and the end of a message ( `03` )
3 - subscribe something to step 2 that will take care of the data.

So, my diagram would look like the following:

```
- 05 34 43 31 - - - 12 23 43 - - 02 53 44 5a - - - 52 6a 72 7a - - - 62 32 62 0d - 0a 03 - - - - > 
                             - - 02 53 44 5a - - - 52 6a 72 7a - - - 62 32 62 0d - 0a 03 - - |
```

### Questions

1 - Since I am receiving this data via a socket in node.js:

```
socket = net.createConnection( { host: "localhost", port: 8080}, () => {
    socket.on( "data", console.log );
} );
```

I don't think I can use the [EventEmmiter](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/gettingstarted/events.md#converting-a-nodejs-event-to-a-rxjs-observable-sequence) bridge that rxjs offers. I would have to use `Observer.create`, correct ?

2 - Even if I solve problem 1, I have no idea whatsoever on how I would create a stream of streams for this effect. Could someone post a code snippet as an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are on the right track.  However, you want to create an observable so you probably want `Observable.create` and not `Observer.create`.  It is very confusing because `Observable.create` needs a function which takes in an `Observer`.  That function can then emit items into that `Observer`.

You are also keen to recognize that you want a hot observable.  However, `Observable.create` is going to give you a hot observable anyways.  You will still want to use some kind of publish to avoid multiple subscriptions.  We will do that with `share`.  As for the buffering, you can probably use `buffer`.  At the end of the day I think it would be something like...

- **A** - An observable created with `Observable.create` wrapped around your socket callbacks.
- **B** - Wrap **A** with [`share`](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/share.md)
- **C** - flatMap **B** to go from a stream of buffers to a stream of items
- **D** - Watch **C** and use [`filter`/`where`](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/where.md) to only emit on `03`.
- **E** - [`buffer`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-buffer) **C** using **D** as your closing selector

Then expose **E** as the public API of your service.  **E** will emit the entire message any time a message arrives.

*Note, this method assumes you get messages back-to-back and thus we don't bother with the `02` signal as we know the first byte after the end of a message must be the start of the next message.  If this is not the case you will want to handle that better.

** You can share after the `flatMap`.  This will be slightly more performant.  You cannot share after the buffer.

*** On a re-read of your question I noticed you want a stream of streams and not a stream of arrays.  To get this result you can take the output of `buffer` and run it through `flatMap` using `Observable.of`  This will give you hot stream of cold streams.